# Wrapping events in dynamic methods

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

In my unit tests, I'm trying to dynamically wrap an event, so that I can inject some test code before forwarding to the actual handler. This is what I have now:

```
Delegate handler = // the original method handler
object myObject = // the original object

EventInfo ei = myObject.GetType().GetEvent("MyEvent");
Delegate d = GenerateWrappedDelegate(ei);
ei.AddEventHandler(myObject, d);

...

private GenerateWrappedDelegate(EventInfo eventInfo)
{
    var eventHandlerType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
    int arity = eventHandlerType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters().Count();
    var methodName = string.Format("Arity{0}", arity);
    var eventRegisterMethod = typeof(EventMonitor).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventHandlerType, this, eventRegisterMethod);
}

private void Arity1(object arg1)
{
    Handle(() => handler.DynamicInvoke(arg1));
}

private void Arity2(object arg1, object arg2)
{
    Handle(() => handler.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2));
}

private void Handle(Action action)
{
    // Do something interesting here, before the original event handler is called
    action();
}
```

I have a fair bunch of these `Arity` methods, because I don't know in advance how many parameters my event will have, and I want to pass them all on to the original delegate.

All this works fine if my event handler delegates look like this:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event MyDelegate MyEvent;
```

However, some of the delegates in our code base don't look like 'traditional' event handlers, but more something like this:

```
public delegate void MyOtherDelegate(object sender, int updatedValue);
public event MyOtherDelegate MyOtherEvent;
```

And then, my code suddenly doesn't work anymore; it fails on the `int`.

I've worked around this problem by adding a convoluted `if` statement in `GenerateWrappedDelegate` and added `Arity` methods, like this:

```
private void Arity2oo(object arg1, object arg2)
{
    Handle(() => handler.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2));
}

private void Arity2oi(object arg1, int arg2)
{
    Handle(() => handler.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2));
}
```

But that obviously doesn't scale very well, and it's painfully redundant.

I've been looking into generating dynamic methods as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx), but this confuses me even more. I'm not familiar with MSIL, and I wouldn't know how to generate a method body that loads all parameters, based on their run-time type, and call `DynamicInvoke` with each of them. I imagine it wouldn't look pretty.

We're using .NET 4.0, so I've been looking into `dynamic` as well, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to make that work, either.

I'm out of ideas. Do you have any?

Comment: @EliArbel Sure, with a little tweaking I can probably make it static!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails on `int` because covariance/contravariance in .NET doesn't work with value types (which would have to be boxed). You can solve this immediate problem using generics:

```
private GenerateWrappedDelegate(EventInfo eventInfo)
{
  var eventHandlerType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
  var parameters = eventHandlerType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters();
  var methodName = string.Format("Arity{0}", parameters.Length);
  var eventRegisterMethod = typeof(EventMonitor)
        .GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .MakeGenericMethod(parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());

  return Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventHandlerType, this, eventRegisterMethod);
}

private void Arity1<T>(T arg1)
{
  Handle(() => handler.DynamicInvoke(arg1));
}

private void Arity2<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{
  Handle(() => handler.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2));
}
```

While this doesn't cover all possible delegates (for example, ref/out parameters would require separate overloads) I suspect it's highly unlikely that you'd encounter events with such signatures.

Comment: So simple and elegant; I wish I would've thought of this myself :). Thanks! And I agree with the ref/out parameters.